# Python - curly braces in type hints

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

What do these mean?

```
 def f(a: {int, float}):
    pass
```

I've seen this syntax used in some standard Python modules when fetching documentation via PyCharm, and I have no idea what it means. What's the hinted type for `a` in my example? What types can I pass to this function?

The particular example where I've seen this is in `tkinter`'s `Frame` `__init__` method, where the `master` parameter is of type `{tk, _w}`.

Comment: looks like `f` can take a parameter `a` of type `int` or `float`

Comment: Can you name one such package? For Python it's equivalent to a comment, but other libraries like Mypy can use them to analyze code.

Comment: variables don't have fixed/permanent type in python.  Hints are a linter feature

Comment: curly braces can be used for sets and dictionaries; it might be specifying one of those.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Edited.

Comment: @DougCoburn Edited.

Comment: @EnnMichael The `__init__` here looks different to me: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2724 Please add a link to it in your question.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Which is interesting - when I fetch the documentation using PyCharm, it shows otherwise. Any idea why?

Comment: That is definitely a `set` literal.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I've created a package for runtime checking of parameters. It doesn't check setting inside a function, though. [Link](https://github.com/jhpratt/type_check.py)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a hint telling you it wants an object with the named attributes 'int' and 'float' -- or more specifically for tkinter 'tk' and '_w'

I coded up a minimal example in pycharm:

[image]

Inpecting the python library [sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py) -- You can see that there are attempted accesses to `master.tk` and `master._w`. That's all that pycharm was able to infer about the type of the parameter master so it floated it up to the IDE in this manner.

Comment: This is correct (you can verify it by testing), but I can’t find it documented anywhere and I’m not even sure what this feature is called. Do you know where this is documented?